# Why PIL draw polygon does not accept numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

This code works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

A = (
    (  2,  2),
    (  2, 302),
    ( 302, 302),
    ( 302,   2)
)

img = Image.new('L', (310, 310), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(A, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(img)

print(mask)
```

However, if the A matrix is provided as numpy array:

```
A = np.array(
    [[  2,  2],
     [  2, 302],
     [302, 302],
     [302,   2]], dtype="int32"
)
```

it produces completely wrong result. I also try to flatten the A array, it does not help.

Do I miss something? Can I stuff the numpy array somehow directly into PIL?

Comment: Is the code working? Your desired outcome was a filled square?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### If call-interaface says use a list-of-tuples or a list of interleaved values,

best use a list-of-tuples or a sequence / list of interleaved values:

> ***`PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon( xy, fill = None, outline = None )`***
>   Draws a polygon.
>
> The polygon outline consists of straight lines between the given coordinates, plus a straight line between the last and the first coordinate.
>
> **`xy`** – Sequence of  
> **either**
>  2-tuples like **`[(x, y), (x, y), ...]`**
> **or**
> numeric values like **`[x, y, x, y, ...]`**.

---

### Can I stuff ..

Using

```
>>> xy
array([[ 2,  3],
       [10,  3],
       [10,  0],
       [ 2,  0]])
>>> xy.flatten().tolist()
[ 2, 3, 10, 3, 10, 0, 2, 0 ]
>>>
```

shall work and meet the PIL-documented-Call-Interface for **`ImageDraw.polygon()`**